# Metric Tensor and Dot Product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I have $A=(1,2)$ and $B=(3,4)$ in Euclidean space. I am asked to compute the $\vec{A}^{\,}\cdot\vec{B}^{\,}$, but by using the following metric:

$g_{11}=a\cos^{2}\phi \sinh^{2}\eta+a^{2}\sin^{2}\phi \cosh^{2}\eta$, $g_{12}=0\,,\, g_{21}=0\,,\, g_{22}=a\cosh^{2}\eta \sin^{2}\phi+a^{2}\sinh^{2}\eta \cos^{2}\phi$

Following are the transformation relation:

$x=a\cosh\eta\, \cos\phi$
$y= a\sinh\eta\, \sin\phi$

In Euclidean space, the value of the dot product is $11$, but I do not know how to compute it with the help of the metric mentioned above. All I know that it should equal $11$, because space is still flat represented in different coordinates.

Comment: What you're looking for is $g_{ij} A^{i} B^{j}$

Comment: The point is that it is not said in which coordinates $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are given, if it is given in cartesian coordinates or in the new (I guess elliptical ?) coordinates. The space stays Euclidean upon a coordinate change (think of spherical or polar coordinates.

Comment: It is what I know. But how can I compute the dot product by using this metric explicitly?

Comment: Metric becomes a function of $\eta$ and $\phi$ after transformation. What values of $\eta$ and $\phi$ should I use to get the value $11$?

Comment: What Eletie has written above is how you do it, that's how you calculate the dot product for an arbitrary metric. The usual Euclidean metric is the identity matrix which makes things simpler, but you are still doing the same thing.

Comment: Try calculating the components of your vectors $A$ and $B$ in your new coordinate system $(x,y)\rightarrow (\eta,\phi)$

Comment: I have already transformed the components of vectors into my new coordinate system, but when I compute the dot product using the metric, I do not know which vectors' $\eta$ and $\phi$ should I use so that my metric entries become numbers and ultimately, I get $11$ as an answer.

Comment: You have incomplete information, you have to know the point $(\eta, \phi)$ at which the vectors are placed.

Comment: @Javier or you can have a symbolic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\eta = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} x + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} y$

$\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} x + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} y$

*But*, notice that these partial derivatives are going to be difficult to calculate. So, forget that. Don't find these contravariant components. Find the covariant components instead.

$\eta_{covariant} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \eta} y$

$\phi_{covaraint} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} y$

These partial derivatives are easier.

Then use $A^i =g^{ij} A_j$ to raise the indices.
Finally, take the dot product using  $g_{ij} A^i B^j = A^i B_i$ (either the RHS or the LHS).

---

$dx/d\eta= a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi)$

$dy/d\eta= a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)$

$dx/d\phi=-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)$

$dy/d\phi=a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)$

$n_{covariant}=A_{\eta}= a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) x +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)y$

$\phi_{covariant}=A_{\phi}=-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)x+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)y$

$A_{\eta}= a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) 1 +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)2$

$A_{\phi}=-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)1+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)2$

$B_{\eta}= a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) 3 +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)4$

$B_{\phi}=-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)3+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)4$

Raise the index of A.

$A^\eta =g^{\eta \beta} A_{\beta}$

$=g^{\eta \eta} A_{\eta}$

$=\frac{a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) 1 +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)2}{[a\cos^{2}\phi \sinh^{2}\eta+a^{2}\sin^{2}\phi \cosh^{2}\eta]}$

$A^{\phi}=\frac{-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)1+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)2}{a\cosh^{2}\eta \sin^{2}\phi+a^{2}\sinh^{2}\eta \cos^{2}\phi}$

$A^i B_i =A^{\eta} B_{\eta} + A^{\phi} B_{\phi}$

$=\frac{a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) 1 +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)2}{[a\cos^{2}\phi \sinh^{2}\eta+a^{2}\sin^{2}\phi \cosh^{2}\eta]}[a\sinh(\eta) \cos(\phi) 3 +a\cosh(\eta) sin(\phi)4]+$

$\frac{-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)1+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)2}{a\cosh^{2}\eta \sin^{2}\phi+a^{2}\sinh^{2}\eta \cos^{2}\phi}[-a\cosh(\eta)sin(\phi)3+a\sinh(\eta)cos(\phi)4]$

It seems to check out, but I'm (probably) not going to simplify it. It's probably possible to simplify it with trig identities.

[wolfram1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5B%5Bcosh%28x%29sin%28y%29%2B2sinh%28x%29cos%28y%29%5D%2F%5Bcosh%5E2%20%28x%29%20sin%5E2%20%28y%29%20%2Bsinh%5E2%28x%29%20cos%5E2%28y%29%5D%5D%5B-cosh%28x%29sin%28y%293%2Bsinh%28x%29cos%28y%294%5D%20%20with%20x%3Dpi%2F2%20and%20y%3Dpi%2F2)

[wolfram2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5Bsinh%28x%29%20cos%28y%29%20%20%2B%202cosh%28x%29%20sin%28y%29%5D%2F%5Bcos%5E2%20%28y%29%20sinh%5E2%20%28x%29%2B%20sin%5E2%28y%29%20cosh%5E2%28x%29%5D%5D%20%5Bsinh%28x%29%20cos%28y%29%203%20%2Bcosh%28x%29%20sin%28y%294%5D%20with%20x%3Dpi%2F2%20and%20y%3Dpi%2F2)

And 8+3=11.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the scalar product is invariant under coordinate transformations.

If we have a coordinate transformation $x'_i =x'_i(x_i)$, where $x$ are cartesian coordinates, the transformation law of the metric is given by (distinction between contra- and covariant components is not necessary in Euclidean space):

$$g'_{ij}  = \delta_{kl}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial x'_j}  =\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x'_j} $$

where $\delta_{ij}$ represents the components of the metric tensor in cartesian coordiantes, i.e. $\delta_{ij} =diag(1,1,1)$

And then we get:

$$\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} = \delta_{kl}A_k\, B_l = g'_{ij}(x')A'_i(x')\, B'_j(x')
 \tag{1}$$

Here the unprimed components of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are those in cartesian coordinates, whereas the primed components are those in the new coordinates (I guess elliptical ones). The invariance is obvious through the summation rules, of course taking into account that the metric tensor is a real tensor (not like Christoffel symbols) and  $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ transform like vectors.

So the conclusion is that the scalar product is $11$ in cartesian as well as in the new coordinates.

For completeness the formula to change the vector components from one system to the other coordinate system are given:

$$B_i =\frac{\partial x_i }{\partial x'_k}B'_k$$

Of course the computation of the components can turn out to be quite tedious.
The components in the curvilinear coordinates (in cartesian ones there the same at all $x$) can certainly vary from one x' to another one. So in order to check equation (1) one can make a cross-check at a (cleverly) chosen (so that's easy) $x'$ --- of course that's no proof -- or to show it at an arbitrary $x'$. Again, it should work out but the computation can be really complicated.

Comment: I believe that this is a homework problem where the questioner is being asked to explicitly compute the new coordinates of the vector.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: it the post it is written: "  I am asked to compute the ⃗ ⋅⃗ , but by using the following metric ...". If it was more clearly expressed in the comments, then OP should change the post. Of course one could classify this a homework problem, but it seems that conceptual issues prevent from solving it properly.

Comment: @FredericThomas the OP did say they knew it should still be the same value in both coordinate systems, so I don't think it's a conceptually issue. The question seems to be how to transform the vector components and do the calculation *in order to get the correct value* of $11$.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong (since I don't do relativity) but if your metric is

$$ \mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix} a\cos^{2}\phi \sinh^{2}\eta+a^{2}\sin^{2}\phi \cosh^{2}\eta & 0 \\ 0 & a\cosh^{2}\eta \sin^{2}\phi+a^{2}\sinh^{2}\eta \cos^{2}\phi \end{bmatrix} $$

Then the dot product should be just the quadratic form:

$$ p = A^\top \mathbf{G} B $$

Comment: $(1,2) \mathbf{G}\binom{3}{4}$ is certainly not 11.But that's the instruction of the post.

Comment: @FredericThomas (1,2) $\mathbf{G}\binom{3}{4}=11$ if $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{1}$ which is what the posts says I think.

Comment: I mean your post, where $\mathbf{G}$ is defined and used two lines below.

Comment: @FredericThomas - quote the _op_ "In Euclidean space, the value of the dot product is 11", the metric tensor is the identity for Euclidean space with only distance coordinates. Is this, correct?